# PHP regex breaking special characters

Tags: php, html, regex, character-encoding, special-characters

```
var_dump(
  preg_replace( 
    array( 
      '#[\s\n\\n]*<[\/\s]?(br|/p|/div)[\/\s]?>[\s\n\\n]*#iu', '#\s+#' ), 
      ' ', "A 19th century Dutch walnut secrétaire à abattant") 
    )
  )
);
```

The result is:

```
string(102) "A 19th century Dutch walnut secrétaire � abattant"
```

Why does my Regex breaking special character in PHP?

Comment: I find it rather strange that it still retains `é` but not `à`.

Comment: Add meta tag <meta charset="utf-8"> after <head> tag

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry, read wrong debug trace

Answer (score 1):

If you set your character encoding right, there is no issue. See your code run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/587017).

Make sure to have this in your html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

And also save your PHP file as UTF-8 encoded. Depending on your editor this might be an option in the "Save As" dialog, or under the "preferences" or "options" menu.

Comment: Did this answer suit your needs? Could you give some feed back?