# PHP: preg_replace doesn't work on htmlentities() result

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, special-characters, html-entities

```
$output = htmlentities("example<br><br>example");
echo $output;

$output = preg_replace( 
  array( '#[\s\n\\n]*<[\/\s]*(br|hr|/p|/div)[\/\s]*>[\s\n\\n]*#iu', '#\s+#' ), 
  ' ', 
  $output );
echo $output;
```

Above code will print `example<br><br>example>` instead of `example  example`. Both `echo` print the same string, `example<br><br>example>`. But I need to keep using `htmlentities()` since if I don't use it, preg_replace will destroy some special characters like `à`. I've mentioned it in this question: [PHP regex breaking special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751209/php-regex-breaking-special-characters)

Does anybody know of any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to remove HTML tags from a PHP string?

Comment: Nope. I want to replace some tags with a space

Comment: A str_replace with array of tags is not enough?

Comment: Can't you replace the tags with spaces first?

Comment: No, str_replace won't be enough since the tag might have a lot of meaningless spaces in it, and unpredictable slash placement.

Comment: I am replacing with space. That's what I want

Comment: Obviously both echos display the same result! First (to understand what happens), display your results between `<pre>` tags. Other thing, your pattern makes few sense, in particular `[\s\n\\n]`. Make small tests, read about `\s`, don't try random things.

Comment: It's not random, and my boss's team made it with a lot of precautios. I know \s. Thanks for the <pre>. Will try

Comment: *I know `\s`*: no you don't, `\s` already contains `\n` and `\\n` is seen as `\n` (the useless backslash is ignored). `[\s\n\\n]` can be written `\s`

Comment: Without to say someone is dumb (that I didn't say), you should consider that you or your boss could make errors (and that is not a shame, it's a normal thing in a learning process), or random things, or a kind of magic things to reach the developer paradise after the death.

Comment: why the `/div`? You want to keep `<div>` and remove `</div>`? That will lead to invalid HTML.

Comment: I will strip the tags after that, so I don't mind about the invalidity

Comment: Any reason why you strip some tags with regular expression and then *strip the tags after that*? Why not strip all at once?

Comment: I want to avoid words sticking to each other after stripping the tags. After a second thought I can do str_replace('<',' <',$string) and then strip the tag. But I'll keep the question open since that won't be a main answer here

Comment: Sublimetext (like PHP) use the pcre regex engine. From the pcre documentation: *"If  the  PCRE2_UCP  option  is  set* [the u modifier] *, the behaviour is
       changed so that Unicode properties  are  used  to  determine  character
       types, as follows:

         \d  any character that matches \p{Nd} (decimal digit)
         \s  any character that matches \p{Z} or \h or \v"*. The singleline flag nor the multiline flag don't change anything.

Comment: @AminahNuraini, did any of the answers suit your needs? Could you give some feed back?

Answer (score 1):

htmlentities replaces `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, so you need to search for the replacements in your regexp.

```
$output = preg_replace( 
  array( '#\s*&lt;[\/\s]*(br|hr|/p|/div)[\/\s]*&gt;\s*#iu', '#\s+#' ), 
  ' ', 
  $output );
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need a `strip_tags` variant that will leave a space between adjacent text nodes, to avoid words clinging together.

One way to do this is using the `DOMDocument` class. You might also want to get rid of the non-printable contents, such as that of `script` tags:

```php
function DOMRemoveTags($dom, $tags) {
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        foreach(iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName($tag)) as $node) {
            $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
        };  
    }
}

function getHtmlText($html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    // Remove some tags together with their content
    DOMRemoveTags($dom, ['script','textarea','iframe']); // extend as needed
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    // Get all text nodes and join them with a space delimiter
    return implode(' ', array_map(function($node) {
        return trim($node->nodeValue);
    }, iterator_to_array($xpath->query('//text()'))));
}

$html = "example<br><br><script>fdsfsd</script><script>222</script>example";
echo htmlentities(getHtmlText($html));
```

By using this DOM API, you avoid some some potential issues that regular expression solutions have: if an HTML string has `<` characters that are not the start of a tag (in text, attribute values, comments, scripts, ...), regular expressions may yield undesired results.